# HealthCare Finder API: Rate Limit?

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

I am trying to determine what the limitations are for someone making calls to the [HealthCare Finder API](https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services/version_3_0). Specifically, does the HealthCare Finder API have any sort of per minute, per hour or per day rate limit for calls to the API?

Comment: I am also trying to determine the same thing and I am wondering if this was answered.

Comment: Please contact the API provider directly. https://www.healthcare.gov/contact-us/ This is a Q&A site not related to HealthCare-Finder-API. When you have an answer from them, please post it here as an answer.